# How to detect a website is changed or not?

Tags: web-access

Such as I want to know the *SE* is change or not. This is my current method

```
StringLength[Import["https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/"]]
```

> `8320`

But when you run it in another time

```
StringLength[Import["https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/"]]
```

> `8058`

As you see,the result is not same,but actually the wesite is not change.. Is there any better method to avoid this problem?

Comment: I guess you'd have to define "changed" because it clearly has changed, only not it a way you are interested in.

Comment: @Kuba Oh,good point,I mean.those content we can see directly have changed.such as some body have post a new question.Then I think it has been changed.

Comment: Are you sure the difference isn't in all those "asked {time}", "modified {time}" ?

Comment: @Kuba Well let me fix [this comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155418/how-to-detect-a-website-is-changed-or-not?noredirect=1#comment414923_155418) a little. Since the content is we can see,then when the new quesion is *Activate*,I think the content is changed and the some body make a bounty question.Then we see a new question in *featured* tag. I also think the content is changed.

Comment: You can only know if a website has changed if you had a copy of the website from before, no?

Comment: Is [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/147778/731) a duplicate?

Comment: There is also the solution to look at the [modified](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23397/731) header, but I would only use that on a static website. Not a dynamically generated one like StackExchange.

Comment: @C.E. Thanks for that links. It seem it duplicate indeed..

Comment: @yode, if what you want is to monitor activity in *mathematica.stackexchange.com* the best option would be to use the **Stack Exchange API** and not to parse the website. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 3):

For instance:

```
active := 
  Module[{str, queslist, timelist, viewlist, votecount}, 
   str = Import[
     "https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest", 
     "XMLObject"];
   queslist = 
    Cases[str, 
     XMLElement[
       "h3", {}, {XMLElement[
         "a", {"shape" -> "rect", "class" -> "question-hyperlink", 
          "href" -> ___}, {ques___}]}] :> ques, Infinity];
   timelist = 
    Cases[str, 
     XMLElement[
       "span", {"class" -> "relativetime", 
        "title" -> ___}, {time___}] :> time, Infinity];
   viewlist = 
    Cases[str, 
     XMLElement[
       "div", {"class" -> "views", "title" -> view___}, ___] :> view, 
     Infinity];
   votecount = 
    Cases[str, 
     XMLElement[
       "span", {"class" -> "vote-count-post"}, {XMLElement[
         "strong", {}, {num___}]}] :> num, Infinity]; 
   Column[{"Mathematica Stackexchange ACTIVE", 
     TableForm[Transpose[{queslist, timelist, viewlist, votecount}], 
      TableHeadings -> {None, {"Question", "Time", "Views", 
         "Votes"}}]}, Alignment -> Center, Dividers -> All, 
    Background -> {{LightBlue, LightGreen}}]];
active
```

[image]